# Does size matter when doing Gmapping with Kinect?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know how big of a robot have people successfully implemented slam using a cheap inexpensive Kinect sensor .

I am currently building a robot as big as jackal platform from clearpath.

All the robots I have seen (mounted with Kinect ) is generally small sized . (Turtlebot , lino bot , pioneer...)

I have simulated the robot on gazebo but the error rate seems to be too high .

How much of an improvement can I expect if I were to use intel realsense D435 ?

I know that visual odometry in this case would be more reliable , but at this point I am kind of inclined towards more off a classical (encoder odometry) based slam approach.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284815/does-size-matter-when-doing-gmapping-with-kinect?/) by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The accuracy of SLAM mainly depends on the `range of the sensor`, `size of the environment compared to sensor Field of view (FoV)` and `uncertainty of motion and measurements`. Generally, Kinect sensor is a low FOV (57 degrees) and short-range sensor (max 5.5m).

Gmapping builds locally consistence map using scan matching and builds a globally consistent map by fusing Rao-blackwellized particle filter. It needs some features ( objects) in the FoV to build a consistent map.  If enough features are not available in sensor FoV for few frames, the local estimation will not give a good accuracy.

Also, the noise of the sensor is a quadratic function with the range of measurements. This also leads the wrong estimation of local maps. Therefore, Kinect can provide a promising result with Gmapping for small-scale environments.

You can use a higher number of particles to get more accurate maps. But, very large number of particles also may lead to diverge the estimation, because, there a higher probability to pick particles with low weights at resampling step.

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3